# Node.JS/C++/Python - edit Excel .xlsx file

Tags: c++, python, excel, node.js, read-write

I'm looking for a way of editing and save a specified cell in Excel 2010 .xlsx file from Node.JS. I realize, that maybe there are no production-ready solutions for NodeJS at this time. **However, NodeJS supports C++ libraries**, so could you suggest me any suitable lib compatible with Node?

Also, I had an idea to process this task via Python (xlrd, xlwt) and call it with NodeJS. What do you think of this? Are there any more efficient methods to edit XLSX from NodeJS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have 2 possibilities:

1. node.js does not support C++ libraries but it is possible to write bindings for node.js that interact with a C/C++ library. So you need to get your feet wet on writing a C++ addon for the `V8` (the JavaScript engine behind node.js)
2. find a command line program which does what you want to do. (It does not need to be Python.) You could call this from your JavaScript code by using a child-process.

First option is more work, but would be result in faster executing time (when done right). Second possibility is easier to realise.

P.S.: To many question for one question. I've no idea about the xls-whatever stuff, besides it's "actually" only XML.

Comment: I think NodeJS binary addon, getting access to C++ xls library, will be the perfect solution. I'll try to find any open source C++ lib, thanks.