# How to work with excel files in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am new in Node.js development and i don't know how to import excel file in Node.js. And how to display excel data in browser any help related to this will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Please stop asking the same questions in different formats. Read the FAQ for what types of questions are good fits for Stack overflow. Asking for code, libraries, etc without showing what problems you've encountered aren't good fits.

Answer (score 1):

Check those links:

https://npmjs.org/package/excel

&

[Node.JS/C++/Python - edit Excel .xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007460/node-js-c-python-edit-excel-xlsx-file)

Comment: i have also npm excel but dispaly data in node.js server side, how to display excel file data in browser side.Source code of display excel file data in browser.

Comment: You will need to send back a formatted html response containing the data from the Excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can browse on npmjs.org to find a package that helps you in it.
For example:
https://npmjs.org/package/excel

Or if you want the raw file, you can also use fs:
http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html